# Sqlite- Show results in desired order

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-cursor

I have created a sqlite table with two columns -**Code** and **Name** and stored data in it. User is provided a searchview to enter code or name and the app show results accordingly.

I am using below query to fetch results-

```
cursor = db.query(TABLE_SEARCH, columns, COLUMN_CODE + " LIKE '" +
        searchText + "%' or " + COLUMN_ NAME + " LIKE '%" + searchText + "%'", null, null, null, null)
```

But the problem is that doesn’t show results in desired order.
I want to show results in below order-

1.On top show results with the Code exactly matching with the searched text.

2.Below that show results with the Name  exactly matching with searched text.

3.Below that show results with the Code starting with the searched text.

4.Below that show results with the Name  containing the searched text.

If I run multiple sqlite queries it makes the search slow.How can I accomplish my requirement in best way without affecting performance?

Comment: If it is already slow, then setting a complicated sorting will make it even slower. Do you have indexes on the columns Code and Name?

Comment: @forpas Its NOT already slow..But i don't want to make it slow..I have rowId in db table

Answer (score 1):

The last argument of the `query()` method is the ORDER BY clause.
Try conditional sorting:

```
cursor = db.query(
    TABLE_SEARCH, 
    columns, 
    COLUMN_CODE + " LIKE '" + searchText + "%' OR " + 
    COLUMN_ NAME + " LIKE '%" + searchText + "%'", 
    null, 
    null, 
    null, 
    "CASE " + 
    "WHEN " + COLUMN_CODE + " = '" + searchText + "' THEN 1 " +
    "WHEN " + COLUMN_ NAME + " = '" + searchText + "' THEN 2 " +
    "WHEN " + COLUMN_CODE + " LIKE '" + searchText + "%' THEN 3 " +
    "WHEN " + COLUMN_ NAME + " LIKE '%" + searchText + "%' THEN 4 " + 
    "END, " + COLUMN_CODE + ", " + COLUMN_ NAME
)
```

For better performance, you should set indexes for the columns `COLUMN_CODE` and `COLUMN_ NAME`.
Also by concatenating so many strings you risk [sql injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). 
I hope you do check if `searchText` contains single quotes and change them to double single quotes, like:

```
searchText = searchText.replace("'", "''");
```

Comment: This is conditional ordering and can be used in the ORDER BY clause. Can you make a fiddle to try this code? It is strange that it does not work.

Comment: Thanks..I don't understand what you mean by setting indexes for columns?..I am setting rowid.

Comment: Indexes speed up search operations. You can find more here: http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-index/